# Ingress NEUTRAL Portals in Pokémon GO

Tags: ingress, pokemon-go

I read that some of the portals that exist in Ingress are Pokéstops or Gyms in Pokémon GO. But are we talking only about the blue portals, or are the Neutral Portals (the grey ones) also Pokéstops/Gyms?

Comment: There is some overlap for bigger landmarks. Ingress has more portals in general, but it would be nice to see someone take a sample of Ingress portals and see where they match in PKMNGO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portals in Ingress do not permanently belong to one faction. Any portal can become neutral, blue, or green depending on the player actions. You can consider all the portals on the [Ingress Intel](https://www.ingress.com/intel) map to be possible sources of Pokemon Pokestops and Gyms.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for your answer! I was kinda nervous about it, because I live in a rural place in Portugal, and my area only has 4 grey portals in the Ingress map (No one plays Ingress here)! Maybe there is a chance that at least one of them becomes a Poké stop!

Comment: @TheLigzyLizard have you considered playing Ingress and turning them blue? =)